# Ignore # array keys in php foreach loop

Tags: php

I am trying to loop over certain array keys in drupal, but this is more of a generic php array question.

The array looks something like this...

```
$form['items'] = array(
  #title  =>  'hello',
  0       =>  array(
               #subtitle => 'hello2';
              ),
  1       =>  array(
               #subtitle => 'hello2';
              ),
  #prefix =>  '<div>hello</div>',
);
```

As you can see, the keys are a mix of numeric keys and #meta keys.

I am using this...

```
foreach($form['items'] as $x) {
  unset($form['items'][$x]['column1']); 
}
```

But i only want to target the numeric keys, I have tried **is_numeric** but it returned false.

Can someone tell me how to ignore the other keys? (Ignore #title and #prefix etc)

Comment: The `#` symbol in php starts a line comment. If your array declaration looks literally like the one that you pasted, `$form['items']` contains 2 empty arrays and nothing more. Unless Drupal does some weird magic.

Comment: Yeah i think its a Drupal thing, the answer below sorted it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to check the keys, but you are using the value in your `foreach`. Do the following:

```
foreach($form['items'] as $key => $value) {
    if (is_numeric($key))
        unset($form['items'][$key]); 
}
```

Hope I was helpful

Answer (score 2):

Use `is_int()` rather than `is_numberic()`

```
foreach ($input_array as $key => $val) {
  if (is_int($key)) {
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

Important to note that `is_int` only works on things that are type integer, meaning string representations are not allowed.